# Extending Angular function to execute script on JSON dynamically

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, dynamic-script-loading

I am designing a platform for a site, where site users are allowed to execute scripts on JSON in browser window only

Here is a screen shot of page:

[image]

user will be getting the JSON, and whatever script is written in form will execute on JSON.

I am using AngularJS as my front end scripting tool.
I know there are ways to execute script using JavaScript eval() funciton. Also another way to execute script is

```
function runMe() {
        console.log('here you  go');
}
var fnstring = "runMe";
var ex = window[fnstring];
ex.apply();
```

But I am looking for a better approach in JavaScript/AngularJS only. Is there any way through which I can extend my Angular Scope function dynamically. Or is there any other Object oriented approach, I should use in order to maintain the script execution safe and optimize.

Comment: What do you mean execute on Json?

Comment: @Wawy : execute on Json means, basic javascript operation (push,indexOf,etc ) that will be written in script will apply on(execute upon)  Json and will modify the json data accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment you could do something like this:

Assuming you store your JSON in a variable called myArr.

You could execute expressions against that Array:

```
var myArr = [{a: 1}];
var expression = "this[0].b = this[0].a + 2"; //example expression
$parse(expression)(myArr);
console.log(myArr[0]);
```

More on angular expressions: [AngularJS docs on expressions](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression)

And $parse: [AngularJS docs on $parse](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$parse)